# Using PHP classes to output html

Tags: php, facebook, oop, scope

I asked the same question earlier and it got down voted and I have no idea why. I'm building a class that outputs a news feed, but it's a very structured html that I'm going to use a lot on the site (hundreds of times), so I'm using a class method to display the feed html and everything. And I just echo the whole thing.

The method is set up this way:

```
private function feed ($var)
{
    $Statement = $this->Database->prepare("SELECT * FROM feed WHERE col = ? ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 50");
    $Statement->execute(array($var));

    while ($row = $Statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        echo '  <div class="feed-box">
                    <a href="feed.php?id=' . $row["facebook_id"] . '">' . /*facebook name retrieved from the facebook */ . '</a>
                    ' . $row["post"] . '
                    <br/>
                </div>';
    }
} //end feed
```

The class is set up so that another method that has more of the html template calls this feed method. (I'm not trying to be too redundant here, but again the last time I asked this question it got down voted).  So I'm pretty new to oop, and I'm looking to display the profile pictures of people who are logged in with facebook. This isn't necessarily a facebook question because I know how to do it normally, but I don't know how to get the facebook information within the class scope using just their id. Normally I;d get their picture by going linking to this url https://graph.facebook.com//picture. How do I do this within the class when I only sotre their facebook id in the database? I've been working on this problem for a couple days now, and I can't figure it out on my own. So I really appreciate your help.

It's getting to the point where I just want to statically type everything out because I know I could easily do that, but I'd really love to learn what the proper way is, especially since editing so many of these little boxes if I want to change something one day would be a real hassle. Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it. Let me know if anything is unclear I'll update the questino as soon as I can.

Comment: The "proper" way would be to adopt an MVC-like pattern. Right now you're mixing logic (your DB query) with presentation (your `while`) loop.

Comment: I would be using a template engine like smarty. That way you can reuse your templates, and seperate your display logic from your code.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I do this within the class when I only sotre their facebook id in the database

```
echo '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' .  $row['facebook_id'] . '/picture" />' ;
```

You say you only store the facebook id in your database. That is all you need to display the picture. Just append `/picture` to the user's FB graph link to get the picture.

Comment: well the picture I guess was a bad example. I don't think there's anyways to display their name for example without instantiating the class and using a method. After googling MVC however from Dai's response I think I'll retrieve all the rows from the db and then just foreach through them statically.